# Netbeans for NS-3 ignores breakpoints when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, breakpoints, ns-3

I'm using netbeans IDE to write a ns-3 program. I have configured it correctly and running works perfectly. The problem arises when I want to debug. Every breakpoint added to an ns-3 library works ok, but when I add a breakpoint to my own file, the execution doesn't stop and just ignores the breakpoint.

I've tried to change some debug configurations and to locate breakpoints at different lines of the file and none of them is working.

I'm using netbeans 12.6 in ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the ns-3 version is 3.0 using the MmWave module.

Thanks for all!

Comment: Have you turned off optimizations completely?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I'm not sure, if I'm not wrong, when I enter properties inside my project, in Build it should appear something like additional options, is right? However, in my case the building is done with make (I just followed the [ns-3 tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/HOWTO_configure_NetBeans_with_ns-3)) and nothing similar appears.